# Storybook.js - DSM Integration : Loading issue

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

After publishing HTML storybook to DSM, I see "Loading..." but the storybook does not load.
DSM preview displays the storybook but when published. it continues to display the Loading message

[image]

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -c .storybook -o .out",
    "deploy-storybook": "storybook-to-ghpages",
    "dsm-storybook:publish": "dsm-storybook publish",
    "dsm-storybook:preview": "dsm-storybook preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invisionapp/dsm-storybook": "latest",
    "npm": "^6.13.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.0",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^5.3.9",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.9",
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "^5.3.9",
    "@storybook/addon-centered": "^5.3.9",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.3.9",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-options": "^5.3.9",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.9",
    "@storybook/html": "^5.3.2",
    "@storybook/storybook-deployer": "^2.8.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jquery": "3.4.1"
  },
```

**NOTE: Downgrading storybook to 5.2.1 works. Would like to know the issue with 5.3.9**

Answer (score 0):

They don't support yet the 5.3 configuration file structure. Just delete you main.js file and go back to pre 5.3 config.js file.

Comment: hi, @user3344978 has it helped to you ?